# How to acquire request parameter from url from Oracle Porta HTML Page Skin?

Tags: oracleportal

I hope any of Oracle Portal experts here could help me out regarding this question.

I have a portal template/page that is using a HTML Page Skin. The skin may looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>#TITLE#</title>
</head>
<body>
#BODY#
</body>
</html>
```

By using Oracle Portal, I could add portlets (PL/SQL and Java portlet) to the body section, in its respective template/page. However there is no way that I am aware of that could enable me to add portlets to other section in the HTML Skin, eg in  section.

I need to dynamically change the title with some value that I get from the page URL and query string.

eg. if the page's url is **http://www.example.com/portal/page/portal/examplepagegroup/page1?param1=paramvalue**
so that the title will be '*param1*', and it should be done without javascript technique.

How could I get the request parameter param1 from the URL so that it will be available to the head section? I am thinking of PL/SQL code to be used here, but, I do not how to access query string of current page.

Please comment here if clarification to the question is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The page title is a static attribute of the Portal page. There is no supported way for a portlet to change the page title dynamically at runtime. The rendering engine combines the HTML from each portlet with some HTML it builds itself, and the title is part of what the renderer builds.

What is possible is to dynamically build pages with specific names by calling WWSBR_API.ADD_FOLDER (a folder is the same as a page). See So your portlet could build a page and then redirect to it.

You find the Portal 10.1.4 API at http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/portal/html/plsqldoc/pldoc1014/index.html